# Condition to find out Aws cloudfomration is creating stack or updating stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am working on a scenario where I need to stop my spring boot application whenever aws stack is updated.

I used command

```
"commands": {
                        "1 - shutdown app " : {
                            "command" : {"Fn::Join": ["",["systemctl stop ",{"Ref":"appname"}]]}}
```

This command is working fine if already have stack available. However, In case of creating stack from scratch. The command is not working because application is not available yet.

I am looking for a condition where if we updating the stack above command will run or when we creating the stack, command will not run.

one more alternative come into my mind to check for running java process using `ps -ef | grep java` .

Is there any way to check the output of grep in cloudformation. If PID is available, I will stop the app otherwise, will not run command.

Let me know if you have any other approach to find solution for me.

Comment: Can you just do `systemctl stop $appname || exit 0`?

Comment: @jingx It's working. Thanks!!